Насколько большой профит в SQL от запроса двух полей вместо всех?
Допустим в таблице users есть поля username, email, first_name, last_name. Нужно получить данные username и email.
Если вызвать только эти поля и, соответственно, если вызвать все поля и взять только необходимые.

Ну возьми и замерь. Желательно по сети (чтобы БД и читающая прога были на разных компах).

Не нужные для дела, но получаемые в выходном наборе поля - это мусор. Тащить мусор в дом - это [censored].

Всё зависит от масштабов процесса. Если это какая-то задача, которая запрашивает данные 100 пользователей раз в сутки, то разницы для вас не будет. А вот если это высоконагруженный сервис, пользователей миллион (или миллиард) и у вас на счету каждый байт, переданный по сети, и каждая миллисекунда работы сервиса, то эффект будет заметный.
Даже если не рассматривать оптимальность самого запрос к БД, там могут быть разные варианты в плане эффективности, а рассматривать только звено БД -> бэкенд, то, по грубой прикидке, если вы получаете все поля, а не только необходимые, то вы удваиваете нагрузку на канал между БД и бэкэндом и создаёте лишнюю работу на стороне и БД и бэкенда. Ведь эти данные нужно:

сериализовать на стороне БД
передать по сети от БД к бэкенду
десериализовать в бэкенде

В два раза больше передаваемых полей -> в два раза больше такой работы.
Но всегда при этом нужно смотреть по бизнес-задаче и по условиям в целом. Если эта лишняя нагрузка для вас не существенна, то можно не заморачиваться, забирать всегда все поля из таблицы, брать потом только нужные из них, у вас будет меньше лишнего кода в обвязке БД, сопровождать этот проект будет проще.
Но если это критичный по ресурсам проект, то вам придётся под каждый запрос делать какие-то оптимизации. Вплоть до того, что под каждую задачу делать отдельный маппинг со своими запросами к БД.
Но возможен и вариант, когда в таком проекте данные вообще не будут каждый раз запрашиваться из базы, а будут храниться в локальном кэше для оптимизации, и вам тогда опять же не нужно будет заморачиваться.

Если индекса по полю нет

идет полное считывание таблицы
в процессе для каждой строки проверяется условие
если условие выполняется - строка помещается в результирующий курсор

Если индекс есть и оптимизатор сочтет нужным его использовать (таблица содержит достаточно много записей)

поиск подходящих строк по индексу
для подходящих строк извлечение строки из таблицы по идентификатору строки
помещение строки в результирующий курсор

Далее из результирующих строк содержащих ВСЕ поля Вам просто отдадут те, что Вам нужны.
Вывод: кол-во выбираемых полей на скорость получения данных НЕ влияет

А если мы просим одно поле и это поле есть в кластерном индексе? А если мы просим опять же одно поле и оно указано в индексе через include? )

"А если..." за рамками задачи, про кластер нигде не сказано. А то я могу так "расширить" рамки задачи, что вообще ни один запрос не вывезет без майнфрейма под сервер

Непонятный вывод, как будто оборвался на полуслове

Странно, что я сразу не заметил - перед "влияет" конечно же должно быть "НЕ". Как пропустил...
